# SQL Server auto insert syntax

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have code like below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.auto_insert_biaya_olah()
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @hid VARCHAR(max);
    DECLARE @pos INT;
    DECLARE @len INT;
    DECLARE @val varchar(max);

    SET @hid = dbo.get_pks_kode();
    SET @pos = 0;
    SET @len = 0;

    WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @hid, @pos + 1) > 0
    BEGIN 
        SET @len = CHARINDEX(',', @hid, @pos+1) - @pos;
        SET @val = SUBSTRING(@hid, @pos, @len);

        INSERT INTO PNL_TR_BIAYA_OLAH_PKS (tanggal, id_pks_pengolah, tarif_olah)
        VALUES (GETDATE(), @val, 447.6);

        SET @pos = CHARINDEX(',', @hid, @pos + @len) + 1;
    END
END
```

I get an error like this in navicat:

> [Err] 42000 - [SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ')'.

The error is not showing which line it happens on. I'm using navicat. Thanks in advance.

Comment: and what is `get_pks_kode()` & what is error line?

Comment: get_pks_kode() is my function . i dunno where the error point to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to use parenthesis`()` when there is no parameters

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.auto_insert_biaya_olah
AS
Begin
..
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike functions, `()` are not required while creating procedures that don't have parameters.

Correct syntax for creating procedure is

```
CREATE PROCEDURE YourProcName
```

Comment: No like that we can use parenthesis for procedures also when procedure has parameters.